# How do I list all systemd masked units?

Tags: linux, systemd

Is there an easy way to list all systemd masked units?

I can think of:

```
ls -l /etc/systemd/system/* | grep /dev/null
```

Or (for unit names only):

```
ls -l /etc/systemd/system/* | grep /dev/null | cut -d' ' -f12 | awk -F'/' '{ print $(NF) }'
```

Is there a clearer way?

Comment: You would also need to look in `/run/systemd/system`, which is where "runtime" configuration lives (that is, configuration that will not persist after a reboot).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `--state` option would do the job

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=masked
```

Answer (score 11):

I think the best way of getting this information might be:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep masked
```

Or, for just unit names:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | awk '/masked/ {print $1}'
```

Of course, either of those expressions would actually match units that contained "masked" in the name.  More accurate would be:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | awk '$2 == "masked" {print $1}'
```